# Fastest way to travel between London and Sheffield by train or airplane

Tags: air-travel, trains, uk, london

I need to go and come back a lot between London and Sheffield for the next year. What is the fastest way to travel between these two. I looked into trains time-tables and they are all 2 hours+.

Comment: Well it is over 150 miles. How long were you expecting it to take?

Comment: @AakashM Less than two hours by train, or 1 hour by airplane. Sheffield is one of the biggest cities in EU, so ideally should have an airport so I can travel from London.

Comment: @DaveRose 150 miles is too less to be traveled by flight.

Comment: A flight is *never* going to be faster than a 2hr train journey since, in practical terms, you need to be at the airport at least an hour before your flight leaves, but arriving at the railway station 15 minutes before the train leaves is more than enough. By the time you've added half an hour getting to and from out-of-town airports to each end of your journey, you've already spent more time than the train journey would have taken.

Comment: Sheffield's the [46th biggest city in the EU according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_cities_of_the_European_Union_by_population_within_city_limits). I was going to disagree with "one of the biggest cities in the EU" but actually, by population it's between Copenhagen and Lisbon, so, fair enough!

Comment: Bear in mind that other than the Eurostar, there is currently no "High Speed Rail" in the UK.  *Average* speed of 75MPH seems pretty reasonable for "normal speed rail".  Its been more than 10 years since I did this journey regularly, so can't comment on reliability these days.

Comment: Sheffield has relatively poor rail service because it's on the slowest of the three main north-south rail lines in England.  Doncaster, a smaller town 20 miles east of Sheffield, has non-stop trains to London in 1h30, ie averaging about 100MPH, because it's on the much faster ECML.  Only four such a day, but the regular service (which has several intermediate stops between Doncaster and London) is still under 1h45.  Doncaster is actually slightly further from London than Sheffield.

Sheffield is very poorly served by rail compared to other cities of its size in the UK.

Comment: @DaveRose "ideally should have an airport" - There  use to be one, but it was too small to be viable, and there isn't enough available flat land to build a replacement. In its last year of operation it served just 13,000 passengers. The closure was pretty inevitable, as its runway was too short for low-cost airlines' fleets to use it, and there was no room to extend it - and nearby Doncaster (a former RAF base) has plenty of room for expansion and currently about 100 times more passengers than Sheffield ever had. London City has a similar runway, but of course a much bigger customer base.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WikiTravel has a quite extensive guide on [Sheffield](http://wikitravel.org/en/Sheffield). Looking for travel options,

**By Car**

Google Maps suggests that the distance is coverable by car in **3 hours** and is about 160 miles, which seems a reasonable estimate.

**By Rail**

> London St. Pancras, once per hour, operated by East Midlands Trains.

Looking at their website tells me that it would take at least 2 hours and 1 minute to get there, which also seems quite reasonable according to the distance.

**By Air**

Even though Sheffield is a prominent city, the closest airport from the city is [Doncaster-Sheffield Robin Hood Airport(DSA)](http://www.robinhoodairport.com/) which is 35 minutes by car.

This would make it infeasible to travel from London because the distance is simply too short and the train trip would be faster anyway (think boarding into flights and landing, luggage etc.)

Thankfully, airlines seem to agree with that and yes, there are no direct flights from London to Sheffield.

**So, your best bet is to take the train and enjoy the happy ride for 2 hours and 1 minute**.

Answer (score 9):

There are no direct flights from Doncaster-Sheffield Airport (DSA) to any London airport.

Sheffield-London uses the Midland Main Line, which is not a particularly fast main railway line.  The fastest services take two hours and one minute.

Depending on exactly whereabouts in Sheffield you are leaving from, you might be able to use trains from [Doncaster](http://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/timesandfares/KGX/DON/tomorrow/1045/dep), which use the (faster) East Coast Main Line in about 1 hour and 42 minutes.

Note that the UK Government agrees with you that Sheffield-London takes too long, and has started a programme to upgrade the Midland Main Line by 2020, which will reduce timings by about 15 minutes, and by the proposed construction of HS2, which would see trains taking about an hour from London to Sheffield after 2030.

Comment: Would it be possible to add some links or references to your answer? I am having a hard time trying to find info on that train or that station. It is a travel website, so we should assume that it will be normal for people not from the UK trying to visit Sheffield.

Comment: This website gives an indication of the Doncaster-London travel time on the train: http://www.thetrainline.com/train-times/doncaster-to-london-kings-cross

Comment: @AdityaSomani I've added a link for London-Doncaster trains.